# Setting timeout on a socket using arduino-esp32 framework

Tags: arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to set a connection timeout on a secure wifi connection on arduino-esp32 framework. My code is:

```
const uint32_t RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 30;

WiFiClientSecure client;

client.setTimeout(RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);

if (!client.connect(currentHost.c_str(), port)) {
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Cannot connect to %s", currentHost.c_str());
    display(3, " E", "connection lost");
    goto failure;
  }
```

This openes the wifi connection successful, but it logs this error:

> [E][WiFiClient.cpp:236] setSocketOption(): 1006 : 9

0x1006 is defined as

> SO_RCVTIMEO 0x1006 /* receive timeout */

and error 9 is defined as

> EBADF 9       /* Bad file number */

I am stuck here. What means bad file number here, and why is it not possible to set the socket stream timeout this way? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have setTimeOut before the client.connect. You must establish the connection first.

Comment: it may help if you rewrote the code within your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm was having a similar issue with my custom Wifi library `m_wifi..cpp` for the ESP32 ( [see here](https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries#readme) )

Only after studying the official ESP32 library on GitHub [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp), and contrary to what can be found on Google, the timeout input is not in seconds but in milliseconds. So your 30 seconds timeout

`const uint32_t RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 30;`

needs to be corrected to

`const uint32_t RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 30000;`